# Ler XML com XMLDocument em Delphi

Tags: delphi, xml, xmldocument

Eu tenho esse xml, eu não sei como ler e pegar os valores. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:WsobterdadoscolaboradorResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace">
   <WsobterdadoscolaboradorReturn href="#id0"/>
  </ns1:WsobterdadoscolaboradorResponse>
  <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Map" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
    <item>
     <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">empresas</key>
     <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1,2</value>
    </item>
    <item>
     <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">id</key>
     <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">2</value>
    </item>
    <item>
     <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">login</key>
     <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">andre</value>
    </item>
    <item>
     <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">nome</key>
     <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Andr&#xE9; Fernando Rodrigues Lima</value>
    </item>
    <item>
     <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">senha</key>
     <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">376255bd8b21e8a66734694f5907a1d5</value>
     </item>
  </multiRef>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5):

O Delphi, desde versões anciãs, disponibiliza duas units:

> XMLIntf.pas e XMLDoc.pas

Para utilizar basta declarar uma variável IXMLDocument e utilizar seus métodos, são bem intuitivos:

```
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XML:= TXMLDocument.Create(''); //Ou nome de um arquivo, se você for alterá-lo posteriormente
  XML.LoadFromFile('Arquivo.xml');
  XML.SaveToFile('Arquivo.xml'); //Ou '' se você especificar esse mesmo nome na construção do objeto
end;
```

Eu utilizei uma variável `IXMLDocument` ao invés de `TXMLDocument` para o compilador gerenciar a memória automaticamente. Assim você não precisa destruir o componente chamando o método `.Free`

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais simples:
Dentro do Delphi tem uma ferramenta (tools/ XML Mapper), basicamente você vai abri o seu xml que vai ser carregado na janela Document, após isso, lado direito do mouse sobre ele, Select All é depois Create DataPacket from XML.
Vai gera um arquivo final ToDp.xtr. na sua aplicação você vai usar o XMLTransformProvider + ClientDataSet ligado a ele. No XMLTransformProvider tem 2 propriedades, uma você vai apontar para o seu arquivo xml e a outra para o arquivo ToDp.xtr. Após isso você pode carregar os campos no seu ClientDataSet como se fosse uma tabela normal.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, sugiro usar um ClientDataSet.

Para carregar os dados tente:

```
ClientDataSet1.Close;
ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile(´data.xml´);
ClientDataSet1.Open;
```

Para salvar os dados é bem semelhante:

```
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile(ClientDataSet1.FileName,dfXML);
```

PS: FileName é a propriedade do ClientDataSet onde você informa o local do seu XML, ali no LoadFromFile você também pode usar FileName ao invés de escrever o nome do arquivo!